# Can Hystrix Circuit Breaker be closed for some endpoints and open for other

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hystrix

Lets say webServiceA is calling webServiceB's Endpoint1 and Endpoint2.

Now Endpoint1 starts sending an error response, and webservice A is using a Hystrix circuit breaker. Will the circuit be in OPEN state for just Endpoint1 or for all endpoints from webServiceA to webServiceB ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hystrix is not aware of any web service connection, it can be used for anything. For example, if you have a slow DB connection, you can open the circuit for that.

So the answer is no, it will not OPEN a circuit for all endpoints out of the box. However, you can setup your service implementation to behave in that way.

For example:

```
@Service
public class WebServiceA {

  @CircuitBreaker
  public ResponseEntity<?> call(String url, String param) {
     // implementation here
     restTemplate.exchange("http://webserviceA/" + url, ...);
  }

}
```

And the method `call()` will be the only `public` access level method to access `WebServiceA`.